# Using For Each to assign collection to collection data item

Tags: vb.net, collections, blueprism

Working in Blue Prisms vb.net environment and currently building out an LDAP VBO utility. I have the below code, it will return the list of users in an AD Group i.e. `samAccountName`, `givenname` & `surname`.

My namespace imports used are:

```vb
System
System.Drawing, System.Data
System.DirectoryServices
System.Collections.Generic
```

My issue is with trying to loop through the resultset and store each row of data returned in my final collection data item, `colResults`.

I know I'm working with a collection and I'm aware that what I'm doing in my For Each loop is not correct, i.e. compile error:

> "String cannot be converted to System.Data.Datatable"

But I'm unable to resolve.

I've attempted to rewrite and use an index but syntactically I can't use `.Count` with my `Properties.SearchResultCollection`.

```vb
Dim de As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Path)
Dim ds As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(de)
Dim srCol As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection
Dim sr As DirectoryServices.SearchResult

'Try and assume success
Success = True

Try

    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=" + GroupDN + "))"
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName")

    srCol = ds.FindAll()

    For Each sr In srCol
        If Not sr.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("name").Value Is Nothing Then
            colResults = (sr.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("givenname").Value.ToString())
            colResults = (sr.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString())
            colResults = (sr.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("samAccountName").Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next
Catch e As System.Exception
    Success = False
End Try
```

Comment: You don't just say "here's my code, the issue is with this part". You explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, exactly what happens and exactly how that differs from your expectation.

Comment: I'll reformat the ask

Comment: Not clear. What is `colResults`? DataTable?

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes its a datatable, I've made the amendment you suggested and it compiles. Much appreciated :)

Comment: ahh.. I deleted unfortunately. Anyways, problem solved. Good luck.

Comment: Apologies for my question not being properly edited and or if it appears like a lack of effort on my part (not the case), junior dev, first dev job, 1 year of computer sci course done with 3 years left and learning as I go. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just posting the solution that @JQSOFT in case its of use to any one else: 

**colResults.Columns.Add(sr.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("samAccountName").Value.ToString(),GetType(String))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning a DataTable from a code stage in Blue Prism, the code stage doesn't know what the columns of the output parameter are going to be – you'd normally assign a new DataTable to it within the code, define the columns, then fill the rows.

So, you should initialize the `colResults` DataTable at the beginning of your code stage:

```
colResults = new DataTable
' make sure the output parameter has these columns defined (or none at all)
colResults.Columns.Add("givenname")
colResults.Columns.Add("sn")
colResults.Columns.Add("samAccountName")
```

And keep creating DataRows and adding them to the table from within the loop:

```
For ...
    If ...
        Dim newRow as DataRow = colResults.NewRow
        newRow("givenname") = ...
        newRow("sn") = ...
        newRow("samAccountName") = ...
        colResults.Rows.Add(newRow)
    End If
Next
```

[DataRow classes' documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.7#examples) shows a well-detailed example as well.